# Is there a way to check for all form elements, then filter specific select elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I've been attempting to modify some code that I was using previously with jQuery 1.6.4 in a jsp.  What the original task was to filter out all select elements from the jsp code, so I used this:

```
$(':input:not("select")').change(function(){    
// Do something here.
...
```

Then I was told that some of the selects needed to be included, so I thought I'd add in a class like this:

```
(':input:not("select")' || $(!'.dontIgnoreSelect')).change(function(){
// Do something here.
...
```

but the logic is wrong here as the short circuit checks the first condition and then moves on.

I want to catch all other form elements as before, but only filter out the selects that don't have the class assigned to them or use some similar mechanism.  I opted for a class as it's going to be used with multiple jsps.

I realized the orignal code won't work, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':input:not("select"), .dontIgnoreSelect');
```

I'm surprised the first part of the expression works, but whatever.

Comment: Well I looked at the jQuery docs and came up with it on my own, but yes it works.  Probably not good for performance, but it's a small jsp.

Comment: You nailed it.  I was struggling with this, but many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think following will accomplish your job

```
$(':input:not("select"), select.dontIgnoreSelect').change(function() {

});
```

Comment: I believe `:input` also gets `textareas` and possibly more.